# Django reached maximum value of sequence

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

I am running a program that creates millions of records daily, after running this program for over a year it seems like I have reached the id limit on my postgres database.

The error I am receiving is

> django.db.utils.DataError: nextval: reached maximum value of sequence "main_records_id_seq" (2147483647)

Is there a way to extend the maximum id using SQL or the django ORM? Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Django uses by default an [**`AutoField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#autofield) to specify values for the primary key at the database side. An `AutoField` is an [**`IntegerField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.IntegerField), and as the Django documentation says:

> An integer. Values **from `-2147483648` to `2147483647`** are safe in all databases supported by Django.

What you can use instead is a [**`BigAutoField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#bigautofield), which will use:

> A 64-bit integer, much like an `AutoField` except that it is guaranteed to fit numbers from **`1` to `9223372036854775807`**.

If your application generates 2'147'483'647 in one year, you can make use of a `BigAutoField` for 4'294'967'298 years.

You thus can define your model as:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
```

Comment: will the migration be handled by Django automatically?

Comment: I am running the migration right now, it's taking a while because it is being applied to a huge amount of records but it looks like it is working. I'll report back if it finishes or receives an error.

Comment: @HoratiuJeflea: If I add the `id` field to a model on a test project, it indeed makes a migration, and for PostgreSQL, it alters the field (with `sqlmigrate` you can inspect the queries).

Comment: @HoratiuJeflea the migration was handled by Django automatically and was actually applied pretty quick.

Answer (score 6):

This is PostgreSql related only, nothing to do with Django ORM. The solution unfortunately is not trivial, [this](https://medium.com/coffee-meets-bagel-engineering/reaching-the-max-limit-for-ids-in-postgres-6d6fa2b1c6ea) is a good article presenting 4 strategies of the DB id migration, with pros and cons.

Summary of strategies:

1. Change the datatype by using ALTER COLUMN.
2. Create a new table with the same schema butid with type bigint and use INSERT INTO.
3. This strategy is very similar to Strategy 2, except that instead of copying over data in one SQL query, we slowly copy over chunks of
   records over a longer period of time.
4. Add a new column to the table with type bigint. Copy over id values to id_bigint and then rename the new column to id (by
   renaming the existing id to id_old).